# Joining 4 tables and selecting distinct values based on 3 timestamps

Tags: oracle, optimization

I have been trying to remove duplicates from my query results based on the time but I would need to consider 3 different times and i am not sure how to do that. As some of the testing happen multiple times, there are duplicates on the part_id and i would only like to have the last tested results from all the 3 tables.

I am running this query now

```
select lb.request_ky,
lb.build_dm,
lb.part_id,
dv.date_test,
dv.result,
dw.date_test,
dw.result,
tt.date_test,
tt.result

From tableA lb,
tableB dv,
tableC dw,
tableD tt

Where lb.part_id = dv.part_id
And lb.part_id = dw.part_id
And lb.part_id = tt.part_id
```

This query would give me duplicates on the part id. How can i just get the latest result from each table and join them together?

Comment: Have you used "group by" clause in your query.

Comment: How is the "latest" defined? By what column?

Comment: tableB, tableC and tableD are tests done and the date_test refers to the date that the testing is done. so latest is defined by the latest for the dv.date_test, dw.date_test and tt.date_test

Answer (score 5):

You have to define first how a "testing" is identified and what "latest" is. Which of the columns identifies a testing and which of the date columns is going to be used for the ordering?

Then, one way to write the query is using window functions:

```
With cte As
  ( Select 
        lb.request_ky,
        lb.build_dm,
        lb.part_id,
        dv.date_test As date_test1,
        dv.result    As result1,
        dw.date_test As date_test2,
        dw.result    As result2,
        tt.date_test As date_test3,
        tt.result    As result3,
        Row_number() Over (Partition By          -- pick a column for the
                             lb.part_id          -- identification
                           Order By              -- and another for the 
                             dv.date_test Desc)  -- order
            As rn
    From 
        tableA lb
      Join tableB dv
        On lb.part_id = dv.part_id
      Join tableC dw
        On lb.part_id = dw.part_id
      Join tableD tt
        On lb.part_id = tt.part_id
  )
Select 
    request_ky,
    build_dm,
    part_id,
    date_test1,
    result1,
    date_test2,
    result2,
    date_test3,
    result3
From
    cte
Where
    rn = 1 ;
```

Comment: so each part undergoes 3 different tests(dv,dw,tt) and the date_test record the date of the test being done. but if the part fails any of the test, it would need to undergo a re-test. when i query it using my query, i would have duplicates of the part_id as it has undergone a re-test.

Comment: dv.results, dw.results, tt.results identifies the testing. dv.date_test, dw.date_test, tt.date_test are the columns used for ordering.  so i think the intent is to get distinct data from dw.results by selecting only data that is latest in dw.date_test and join it with dv.results selecting latest by dv_date.test and join it with tt.results selecting latest by tt.date_test.

Comment: would you mind briefly explaining what the row_number() section does? the query seems to work alright!

Answer (score -3):

Use **JOIN** with **ON** condition. Try as like below

```
Select lb.request_ky,
       lb.build_dm,
       lb.part_id,
       dv.date_test,
       dv.result,
       dw.date_test,
       dw.result,
       tt.date_test,
       tt.result

From tableA lb 
     INNER JOIN tableB dv ON lb.part_id = dv.part_id 
     INNER JOIN tableC dw ON lb.part_id = dw.part_id 
     INNER JOIN tableD tt ON lb.part_id = tt.part_id
Where dv.date_test = dw.date_test 
  AND dw.date_test = tt.date_test
  AND dv.date_test = NOW()
```

All the best.

Comment: thanks for the reply! but it just says NOW is an invalid identifier..

Comment: i think its an oracle database and it does not recognize the NOW() function. i tried using sysdate but there are no results returned at all

Comment: Which database you are using ? . I just used now() for example you can use any timestamp.

Comment: i am using oracle database. but i do not understand how does the timestamp help to return the latest results. there are 3 different tables where the data of 3 different tests are being sent to. in each test there may be re-tests and i would only like the latest results from the tests.

Comment: Use equivalent Oracle function for current timestamp as  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() or CURTIME() whatever you require. For more see here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: i used current_timestamp() and have no results as well. the date_test is not the current time, it might be a few weeks ago or a few days ago... that might be why there is no results returned.

Comment: I just given a example for where statement in Join. You have to find out which columns have to use for condition that are based on your need.

Comment: While I agree that it is better to use an explicit join, your answer does not address the OP's question.